# No of bytes copied from a file to a stream is null

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core

I am trying to copy a file from amazon s3 to a memory stream so that I can pass it as a file to be downloaded.

I am getting the file from amazon s3, however when I am trying to copy the stream I am getting a null value.

I have checked to see if the stream is getting closed before copying and it is not.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
    getObjectRequest.BucketName = Bucketname;
    getObjectRequest.Key = Keyname;

    var getObjectResponse = client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest);
    getObjectResponse.Wait();
    getObjectResponse.Result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
    var len = ms.Length;

    return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "filename");
}
```

Also

```
var len = ms.Length;
```

is giving a value of 18.

So Why is no content being read.
Please do point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's likely that you are looking for data before the Async process is completed. Is there an event associated with this? CopyToAsyncCompleted?

Comment: in what place is "no content being read" ? what makes you think this is the case? `ms.ToArray()` *should* return a `byte[]` with length 18 - is that not the case? note: 18 bytes seems *incredibly* unlikely for a PDF. Are you sure that the problem isn't simply that the call is working, and it is returning an error HTTP response?

Comment: @RossMiller ah, good spot; this should *ideally* be `await ... CopyToAsync(ms)` - however, frankly, since the other code is using `.Wait()`, perhaps just using `... CopyTo(ms);` is more likely; IMO you should expand that to an answer - it seems pertinent

Comment: Yeah. Seems others spotted it too :) Glad to be of help. I'm always wary when I see Async on the end of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
getObjectResponse.Result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
```

Who is waiting for that `Task` to finish? No one, so you return in the middle of the operation.

Overall, the code should be:

```
try
{
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
    getObjectRequest.BucketName = Bucketname;
    getObjectRequest.Key = Keyname;

    var getObjectResponse = await client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest);
    await getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
    var len = ms.Length;

    return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "filename");
}
```

Note the proper use of `await` for asynchronous operations, which you should be using, specially in a web framework like ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` for your `GetObjectAsync` method like below and also for `CopyToAsync` as @Camilo answer :

```
try
{
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
    getObjectRequest.BucketName = Bucketname;
    getObjectRequest.Key = Keyname;

    var getObjectResponse = await client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest);
    getObjectResponse.Wait();
    await getObjectResponse.Result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
    var len = ms.Length; 
    return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "filename");
}
```

or you can do something like:

```
static async Task ReadStream()
{ 
    try
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = keyName
        };
        using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest))
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream(responseStream))
        {
            //your codes
        }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        //Handle it
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Handle it
    }
}
```

the `responseStream` is your stream content
and consuming is something like :

```
ReadStream().Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for your async to return. If your method is not marked as async and you don't want to mark it as such you can do the following:

```
var ms = Task.Run<byte>(async () => await getObjectResponse.Result.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms)).Result;
```

This will execute the async method and wait for the return. You also won't need to mark your function as async.

Comment: Don't use Task.Run to run an `async Task` method, specially an I/O event

Comment: Ok, care to explain why?

Comment: Sure. You are creating a Thread Pool Thread whose only task is to start an asynchronous task which depends on an I/O operation, so this thread does not do anything useful and might lead to thread starvation.

Comment: Ok. I understand this is a code smell, however if you really can't refactor your method to be async, then this will get around the issue. Which is what I was trying to point out.

Comment: That can be the case in some clients, but if you watch the tags for the question you'll see [tag:asp.net-core], which means that asynchronous code is not only available but also wanted. With this, 10 requests could easily block the server